# Find value of $\dfrac{(1+\tan^2\frac{5\pi}{12})({1-\tan^2\frac{11\pi}{12}})}{\tan\frac{\pi}{12}\tan\frac{17\pi}{12}}$

Tags: trigonometry

My attempt :
$$\dfrac{\left(1+\tan^2\dfrac{5\pi}{12}\right)\left(1-\tan^2\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)}{\tan\dfrac{\pi}{12}\tan\dfrac{5\pi}{12}}$$
Change into variable form
$$\dfrac{(1+a^2)(1-b^2)}{ab}$$
$$\dfrac{1+a^2-b^2-a^2b^2}{ab}$$
I'm stuck here also I don't think this is the correct way.

Comment: Use trigonometric identities.

Comment: @cjferes $\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta=1$ use this identity, Am I right?

Comment: **Hint:** Write $$\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$ and simplify. You've to use compound angle results of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Also, your mistake is that $\tan(π-x)=-\tan x$.

Comment: Another way may be noticing that $\tan\frac{\pi}{12} = 2 - \sqrt3$ and $\tan\frac{5\pi}{12} = \cot\frac{\pi}{12} = 2 + \sqrt3$. To calculate $\tan\frac{\pi}{12}$ one may use $\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4}$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{(1+\tan^2\frac{5\pi}{12})({1-\tan^2\frac{11\pi}{12}})}{\tan\frac{\pi}{12}\tan\frac{17\pi}{12}}$$
$$=\dfrac{(1+\tan^2\frac{5\pi}{12})({1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{12}})}{\tan\frac{\pi}{12}\tan\frac{5\pi}{12}}$$
$$=\dfrac{4}{\left(\dfrac{2\tan\frac{5\pi}{12}}{(1+\tan^2\frac{5\pi}{12})}\right)\left(\dfrac{2\tan\frac{\pi}{12}}{{1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{12}}}\right)}$$
Use trig. identity, $\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}=\sin2\theta$, $\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}=\tan2\theta$,
$$=\dfrac{4}{\left(\sin\left(2\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)\right)\left(\tan\left(2\frac{\pi}{12}\right)\right)}$$
$$=\dfrac{4}{\left(\sin\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)\left(\tan\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}$$
$$=\dfrac{4}{\left(\frac12\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right)}$$
$$=8\sqrt3$$

Comment: Sorry, how does $1-\tan^2\frac{11\pi}{12}$ become $1+\tan^2\frac{\pi}{12}$

Comment: The question is actually different if you see. The second bracket in Numerator has  $-$ sign.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Am I misunderstood anything here $1-\tan^2\frac{11\pi}{12}=1-\tan^2\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)=1-(-\tan\frac{\pi}{12})(-\tan\frac{\pi}{12})=1-\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)$

Comment: I have the same question as @Ken asked.

Comment: @Ken: You are very right. I just forgot there is square term. I fixed it thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can write
$$ F=\frac{(1+\tan^2(5\pi/12))(1-\tan^2(\pi/12))}{\tan(5\pi/12) \tan(\pi/12)}$$
$$\implies F=\frac{2}{\frac{2\tan(\pi/12)}{1-\tan^2(\pi/12)}}\frac{\sec^2(5\pi/12)}{\tan(5\pi/12)}.$$
$$F=2 \cot (\pi/6) \frac{\csc^2(\pi/12)}{\cot(\pi/12)}=4 \sqrt{3} \csc(\pi/6)=8\sqrt{3}$$